# Set __doc__ for class in python 2

Tags: python, metaclass, docstring

I am making a large number (close to 100) of classes programmatically and I would like to be able to set the docstring of the class. Each of the class docstrings will have the same basic structure, with specific pieces to be filled in. I would like to define a template string and then populate it with class specific arguments when the class is created.

As a contrived example of what I am after, consider the following

```
class_docstr = """
This is the docstring for the {name} class.
"""


class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass


class C(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

What I would like to do is somehow set `A.__doc__ = class_docstr.format(name="A")` so that when I call `help(A)` I see something like this:

```
class A(__builtin__.object)
 |  This is the docstring for the A class.
```

I believe I might need to use a metaclass to do this, but I am not sure how.

Comment: You can update the `__doc__` key of the class dictionary inside of `__new__` method of a metaclass, note that this has to be done before the class is actually created.

Comment: This would sort of defeat the purpose of docstrings since glancing at the class definition wouldn't give you an obvious way of seeing the documentation.  Is there a reason your docstrings need to be generated in this way?

Comment: I want the docstrings more for interactive exploration at the python or ipython repl and for automatically generating html documentation via sphinx, not to document the source.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Why do you say that it needs to happen before the class is created?  The __doc__ attribute should be writable...

Comment: @mgilson It is not possible with classes that are of type <type>. But hmm... a metaclass makes it possible. http://ideone.com/UPKHq8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the docstring by assigning to the `__doc__` class variable inside the class definition:

```
class A(object):
    __doc__ = class_docstr.format(name="A")

    # whatever else
```

This works, even though assigning to `A.__doc__` does not work later, after the class has been created.

Comment: Great/simple answer. Worked perfectly for my application

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a metaclass here, it shouldn't be hard...

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...   def __init__(cls, *args):
...     super(Meta, cls).__init__(*args)
...     cls.__doc__ = class_docstr.format(name=cls.__name__)
... 
>>> class A(object):
...   __metaclass__ = Meta
... 
>>> A.__doc__
'\nThis is the docstring for the A class.\n'
```

With that said, this is almost certainly overkill...

Comment: I don't really want to use a meta class, but don't know of a cleaner solution. Can you offer an alternative? Perhaps Blckknght's suggestion?

Comment: Sure, that will work.  Then you have to specify the name of the class twice, but that's not the end of the world.  Alternatively, you can create a class decorator to do the job... Basically -- You have a number of options and it really just depends on how verbose you want to be...

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 2, where you can't modify the `__doc__` variable after the class has been created. You can add a `__doc__` value to the class dictionary in a metaclass `__new__` method, but that's a bit more verbose than what you have here.

Comment: @Blckknght It is possible if the class's type is something other than `type`. So, a simple decorator based approach is not possible.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue12773, resolved only for Python 3.3+. :/ Same issue in PyPy 2.4.0 BTW.